# Changing kivymd snackbar font

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Does anyone know how can I change the font of `kivymd` snackbar?
I tried this but it won’t work:

```
Snackbar(text=“hi”,font_name=ex.ttf)
```

Answer (score 1):

The font that you see in a `Snackbar` is the font of the `MDLabel` that is part of the `Snackbar`. That `MDLabel` has an `id` of `text_bar`, so you can access it and change the font. For example:

```
def openSnackbar(self):
    sb = Snackbar(text="This is a snackbar!")
    sb.ids.text_bar.font_name = 'Junkyard'
    sb.open()
```